# How to combine 2 arrays into 1 React

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

I am pretty new to react. Currently i am trying to combine 2 arrays item into one but i would like to iterate over each item. How can i do that?

```
const arr1 = [ { value: "red", label: "Red" },{ value: "yellow", label: "Yellow" },{value: "Blue", label: "Blue" },]

const arr2 =[ { value: "s", label: "S" },{ value: "m", label: "M" },{ value: "l", label: "L" },]
```

Expected result:
["red,s","red,m","red,l"],["yellow,s","yellow,m","yellow,l"]....

I have tried concat() & reduce, but the result i get is two array merge together rather than items merge seperately. Can someone help please?

Comment: You could loop over arr1 and then get the elements that you want to add to the value from the second array.

Comment: Just a quick note that your question has nothing to do with React. Yes, one of the great advantages of React is how easy is to get started with, but still, go over the bare basics of JavaScript first :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use map to manipulate with data.

```js
const arr1 = [ { value: "red", label: "Red" },{ value: "yellow", label: "Yellow" },{value: "Blue", label: "Blue" },]

const arr2 =[ { value: "s", label: "S" },{ value: "m", label: "M" },{ value: "l", label: "L" },]

console.log(...arr1.map(data => {

return arr2.map(data2 => data.value + "," + data2.value)
}))
```

Comment: @BenStephens My mistake , Done changes

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me, using nested loops:

```js
const arr1 = [ { value: "red", label: "Red" },{ value: "yellow", label: "Yellow" },{value: "Blue", label: "Blue" },]
const arr2 =[ { value: "s", label: "S" },{ value: "m", label: "M" },{ value: "l", label: "L" },]

const newarr = []
for (i=0; i<arr1.length; i++) {
    tmp = []
    for (j=0; j<arr2.length; j++) {
        tmp.push([arr1[i].value, arr2[j].value])
    }
    newarr.push(tmp)
}

console.log(newarr)

// [
//   [ [ 'red', 's' ], [ 'red', 'm' ], [ 'red', 'l' ] ],
//   [ [ 'yellow', 's' ], [ 'yellow', 'm' ], [ 'yellow', 'l' ] ],
//   [ [ 'Blue', 's' ], [ 'Blue', 'm' ], [ 'Blue', 'l' ] ]
// ]
```

Answer (score 0):

Give this a try (feel free to change out the keys to either .value or .label)

```html
function mergeArrays(arr1, arr2) {
    let result = [];
    
    for (let i = 0; i < arr1.length; i++) {
        result.push([]);
        for (let j = 0; j < arr2.length; j++) {
            result[i] = [ ...result[i], arr1[i].value + arr2[j].value ]
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Pretty straight forward attempt would be

```
[...arr1, ...arr2].forEach(console.log)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const newArray = [...arr1,...arrr2];
 newArray.map((element)=>{
   return console.log(element)
});
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).